# Alternative to AJAX setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a script that uses ajax to retrieve PHP data for video files on my server (godaddy shared hosting), and then play the video file on my php page if it is the highest ranked video, like so:

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(function refreshscreen () 
  {

    $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'screen.php',                         
  data: "",                      
  pass to api.php

  dataType: 'json',                 
  success: function(data)       
  {
    var id = data[0];
    var name = data[1];   
    var votes = data[2];    
    var video = data[3];
    var image = data[4];

    $('.screen').hide(); $("#video"+id+"").show();

    var whichvideo = "thevideo" + id;
    var videoplay = document.getElementById(whichvideo); 
    var killvideo = document.getElementsByClassName('videobg');


    var allvideos = document.getElementsByClassName("videobg");

    for(var x=0; x < allvideos.length; x++)
    {

    var allvideosid = document.getElementById(allvideos[x]); 

    if ($(allvideos[x]).attr("id") == whichvideo) {
        allvideos[x].play();
    } else {
        allvideos[x].pause(); 
    }

    }

  },
  complete: function() {
  // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
  setTimeout(refreshscreen, 5000); 
  }
  });
  });
```

And then the screen.php referenced above:

```
<?php

  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "myuserhere";
  $pass = "mypasshere";

  $databaseName = "mydbnamehere";
  $tableName = "mytablenamehere";


  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY votes DESC");       
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                        


  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

This all works fine, and the video switches as it should when a new higher ranked video is voted in, however, periodically, the video will freeze when playing, completely at random. My guess is that we are overloading the server with the setTimeout function of the ajax script, so I am wondering if there is a way I can clean up this script to avoid the freezing, or an alternative method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and are **removed as of PHP 7** (released in 2015). This is because they have **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE THEM**. Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: I am aware of the vulnerabilities in mysql_ functions and will be migrating my scripts to mysqli in the near future, thank you for the concern.

Comment: Why would the video freeze because of server overload? are you hosting the videos yourself? If that's the case then that's your problem not ajax. Otherwise I don't see why the video streaming from another host would freeze when you make a request to your own unrelated server.

Comment: @AmrNoman - I am only assuming this is the case. Ive seen where too many repeated setTimeout requests being sent can cause a backload on the server, and I dont beleive its the video itself freezing so much as potentially the browser itself. It is difficult to say with certainty. Also: internet speed is ruled out as being the issue, at least on my end with verified speed tests.

Comment: It's probably the browser, Some debugging tools that intercept ajax calls may cause performance issues. I had that problem with laravel when using debugbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cleaned up the code:

```
var currentID = -1;

function refreshscreen() {
  $.getJSON('screen.php', data => {
    var topID = data[0];

    // Schedule the next request
    setTimeout(refreshscreen, 5000);

    if (topID === currentID) return; // top rated video hasn't changed

    $('.screen').hide();
    $("#video" + topID).show();

    var pauseID = "thevideo" + currentID;
    var playID = "thevideo" + topID;

    $(".videobg").each(function() {
      if (this.id === pauseID) this.pause();
      if (this.id === playID) this.play();
    });

    currentID = topID;
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  refreshscreen();
});
```

The biggest change is keeping track of the currently playing video and exiting right away if it hasn't changed. Other than that I got rid of all the unused variables and used jQuery throughout. This should be much easier to debug at the least and might fix the error to boot.

Comment: this cleaned up my code a great deal, however the issue persists. upon further investigation, what is actually happening is that every time the video switches, the video begins loading ONLY then. I am now looking for a way to pre load all the videos before the page even loads, but for the purposes of my initial question, i am awarding Chris G the answer here.